# in kubernetes how to print current pod rc and service configuration?

Tags: docker

I have a `kubernetes pod` running. I can run

```
# kubectl --namespace=jas get rc myapp
CONTROLLER   CONTAINER(S)   IMAGE(S)                                                          SELECTOR                                   REPLICAS
myapp    myapp      docker-registry/myapp:1.0.0.24-SNAPSHOT_434   name=myapp,version=1.0.0.24-SNAPSHOT   2
```

how can I print the original source file (be it `yaml`) that was `created` in order to have that pod running?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the YAML representation by appending `-o yaml` to it, so: `kubectl --namespace=jas get rc myapp -o yaml` will do the job. See also the [docs](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_get.html) for more options.